# ElasticSearch index has thousands of shards

Tags: elasticsearch

A request to the `_search` endpoint returns the following:

```
{
    "took": 303,
    "timed_out": false,
    "num_reduce_phases": 12,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 6121,
        "successful": 6121,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
```

The number of shards is increasing periodically.
What could cause the number of shards to increase like this?  I do not see any evidence of the shards being explicitly added.

**UPDATE**
The number of shards was for all indexes, not this index in particular.
The high number of shards was simply due to adding several daily log indexes without a proper delete policy.

Comment: How many indexes do you have, do you have daily indexes? Every index will have some shards associated with it based on your index template. Are you deleting  older indexes properly? Try doing a request to `_cat/indices?v` endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shards are set up on index creation, depending on the elasticsearch version the defaults may change.

For the last version it is 1 primary shard and 1 replica, meaning each index will use 2 shards. You can change the number of replicas after creating the index, but not the number of primaries.

Then for example if you have 2 primary shards and 3 replicas index you will have a total of 8 shards ( 2 pri + 2 pri * 3 rep = 8)

Common reasons of seeing shards increasing it is you are ingesting 1 index a day. Many ingestion tools will use the current day as index name, causing a new index generating every day.

You can read more about shards here:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-many-shards-should-i-have-in-my-elasticsearch-cluster